# Vim details autocomplete for Rails

Tags: ruby, vim, autocomplete

I found nice detail autocomplete for python

[image]

Is there analog with description of methods for Ruby on Rails?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a nice article ["Using VIM as a complete Ruby on Rails IDE"](http://biodegradablegeek.com/2007/12/using-vim-as-a-complete-ruby-on-rails-ide/) which references [rails.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1567). This seems to be the de-facto standard on Rails for VIM. (However, I have not used it yet, but will try it soon.) This allows you to do a lot of Rails related tasks, but does not help with auto completion.

There is another article ["Ruby Autocomplete in Vim"](http://www.cuberick.com/2008/10/ruby-autocomplete-in-vim.html) (which is sadly no longer available) which is what you are searching for. I do not know, if it is sufficient clever to understand all the plugin magic and meta-programming stuff of Rails. It mentions Rails at least in its configuration for vim.

So good luck :-)

Comment: Thank you, but I find possible to add description of methods to rails.vim

Comment: The domain of your second link  "Ruby Autocomplete in Vim"  is not available any more (cuberick.com).

Comment: Well, that is the internet. Changes over time, so resources are no longer available. I have not found a copy of it elsewhere, and will adapt therefore my answer.

Comment: The article can still be found in the wayback machine: https://web.archive.org/web/20130702053348/http://www.cuberick.com/2008/10/ruby-autocomplete-in-vim.html